# Django: Page for each image in folder

Tags: python, django

I have a model which is a directory to a folder with images in (in order of filename), to display this I have this in the URL:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)', 'Main.views.read'),
```

and for read it will display all images with this (not too sure if it's the best way but it works so it's OK in my books):

```
def read(request, slug):

        dir_name = slug
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, dir_name)
        images = []
        for f in os.listdir(path):
            if f.endswith("jpg") or f.endswith("png"):
                images.append("%s%s/%s" % (settings.MEDIA_URL, dir_name, f))

        return render(request, 'read.html', {
            'images': images,
            })
```

But I also want the user to be able to go image by image depending on how many pictures are found, how would I go about doing this? Should I make a whole new view or find a way to find if the user goes on a url like so:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)\(?P<page>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', 'Main.views.read'), # different views.* if needed(?)
```